# Output impedance of a series shunt feedback amplifier

Tags: amplifier, impedance, feedback

I am trying to find the output impedance of a series shunt feedback amplifier by converting it to a two port network.

I know the input impedance:

**Ri=ri*(1+A.β)**

But I dont know how I should find the output impedance.

I only know the answer:

**Ro=ro/(1+A.β).**

[image]

Comment: I think you mean **Ro=(ro//Rc) / (1+A•β)** for a collector resistor on Vo to supply rail.  See how the gain changes with load resistor.

Comment: We didn't used transistor on this topic lecture. The topic was basic feedback topologies. It was a block diagram with amplifier and negative feedback loop.

Comment: Ok ignore Rc but check bracket errors in question.  Then add a load that drops gain 50%. that's your output impedance

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

1.) Apply a test voltage Vin between both output nodes. This voltage causes two currents - one current i1 directly into the amplifier (through ro) and another current through the feedback network producing a voltage (Vn=Vin*beta) at the opamp input. Of course, the "actual" input signal Vi is set to zero!

2.) The input voltage Vn will be amplified by the gain (-A) and drives another current i2 through the output resistor ro (Ohms law).

3.) Both currents may be superimposed (added together) because we assume of course linearity. Both currents have the same direction (inverting gain) and the sum (i=i1+i2) leads to a very small output resistance rout=Vin/i.